# After upgrading to rails 3.2.9 cant focus on input

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

I upgraded rails to `3.2.9` after that I cant use jQuery `focus` function in this script:

```
$('#password-clear').show();
$('#password-password').hide();

$('#password-clear').focus(function() {
    $('#password-clear').hide();
    $('#password-password').show();
    $('#password-password').focus();
});
$('#password-password').blur(function() {
    if($('#password-password').val() == '') {
        $('#password-clear').show();
        $('#password-password').hide();
    }
});
```

After I focus #password-clear i stil see #password-clear

How to debug what is going on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you also change your version of jQuery? Do you have any JavaScript errors? If you are using Chrome you can bring up the web inspector (View > Developer > Inspector) and check if any errors are preventing your code from running.